# Did I read the rules for the nomination phase correctly?

Tags: discussion, election

Does

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance ...

really mean that people with lower rep don't get into primary, no matter how good their presentation is ?
I am trying to understand the process, not to criticize it :-)

Comment: Why do you think more than 30 nominees will run? It seems that [last year](http://askubuntu.com/election/2) we only had 10 nominees.

Comment: @gertvdijk thx for the valuable input - to be honest I didn't think about the size of that number at all :-/

Comment: The question looks silly in view of that thought - should I delete it?

Comment: Nah... let's see what happens. Maybe we have a lot more this year - who knows.

Comment: @gertvdijk congrats now we got at least 14

Comment: @smartboyhw Yeah, at this rate of one new nominee per hour we'll be at roughly **170** at the end! (kidding)

Comment: the joys of extrapolation ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What it means is this:

After the 7 day nomination period, where nominees volunteer for the job, if there are more than 30 nominees only the 30 highest ranking in reputation move on.

The last two elections on AU both had less then 10 nominees so there wasn't a primary phase though, so everyone just moved into the election phase.

So in other words, low rep users *can* make into the election, but only if there are less than 30 high rep users.

Comment: So I understood the rules correctly, thx.

Comment: @Seth You may want to make a correction. Last election, everyone moved from the nomination phase into the election phase because there were no more than *10 candidates* (not 30). Otherwise, they would've moved into the primary phase. (When there are more than 30 candidates, only 30 advance to the primary phase. This is the significance of the *30* number.)

Comment: @EliahKagan done, I must have misread it.  I thought they had changed it.